# When to use "he/she had" and when to use "had he/she" when formulating a question?

Tags: sentence-construction, questions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I'm not very sure, but I think the "he/she had" structure is more colloquial/informal? Or maybe I should never use that construction when asking questions?

Here's an example sentence:

> Her hypothesis opened a door to new questions: was her problem some sort of genetic disability? Or **she had/had she** inherited this behavior from her parents?

Comment: English usually uses ***subject/verb inversion*** to form questions, so it's ***Had she [done this]?*** (not ***She had done this***, which is a *statement* rather than a question). It's not normally "colloquial, idiomatic" to use the "subject+verb" sequence in the context of a question. Native speakers do this sometimes (using ***rising intonation*** to signify that it's supposed to be a question), but often it's just seen as an indicator of "non-native speaker", so you should try to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Or *had she* inherited it from her parents?" is grammatically correct. "She had ... [done something] ?" is not acceptable in a normal question, even informally.

Comment: Not relevant to the grammar, but as far as *meaning* goes, it sounds like your might want to eliminate the "Or" in your example, since it makes your statement sound like "genetic disability" and "inherited from parents" are two contrasting possibilities. In fact, genetic disability is often inherited from parents. [Just a note on the use of "or", not meant to answer your query about word order in a question.]